# What's the best document search engine to integrate into Perl code?

Tags: perl, full-text-search, search-engine, kinosearch

What is the best document search engine (perhaps Plucene?) to integrate into Perl code that allows customizing and tuning the search algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [KinoSearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KinoSearch) instead.  Then, read [its tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KinoSearch::Docs::Tutorial).

Comment: Does KinoSearch support customizing search results?

Comment: Yes. Standard +field:(value) and -field:(value) constructs, ie +site:(stackoverflow.com). Kino rocks

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at [swish-e](http://swish-e.org). Really fast, really easy to setup and really flexible. I've used it in lots of projects successfully and it has lots of [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SWISH) [support](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SWISH::HiLiter) [too](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SWISH::API::More):

Comment: I love SWISH-E and it comes with Perl libraries. I have used it on both Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 2):

Just to suggest something else: I've enjoyed [sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/).  One of the next releases is supposed to get proper "real time updates"; but until then it's rebuilding its indexes very fast.

Answer (score 0):

First up, seriously consider Lucene instead - it's much faster and the files it generates are more compatible with other implementations of lucene. There's a dependency on the clucene library but it's worth it if you can.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lucene

Comment: Actually, KinoSearch is the recommended indexing engine for use with Perl.

Comment: The original question was how to set up & use plucene in perl :-)
We used Lucene because it integrates well with other tools & other languages. eg the FAQ index is generated from xml files with an ant task, and our mod_perl servers can read it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What platform? What resources are available? Is this monolithic or something that is deployed. Does this have to handle issues lke revision control as well?

Comment: It would be Linux and monolithic.